# What is wrong with favicons?

Tags: html, web, favicon

I'm trying to create a website but have a problem with favicon. 
Site: http://apelsinblog.ml
Report: http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?site=http%3A%2F%2Fapelsinblog.ml#.Vtx2emCLTIU
I want favicons to work correctly for mobile and Win8/10 platforms, but favicons for these platforms do not work, as you can see from the screenshot.
Please look through HTML. Thank you very much.
Fragment of `<head>` with favicons:

```
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/fi/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/fi/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/fi/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/fi/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/fi/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/fi/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/fi/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/fi/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/fi/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/fi/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/fi/favicon-194x194.png" sizes="194x194">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/fi/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/fi/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/fi/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="/fi/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/fi/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#fc9700">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Апельсин — свежий сайт">
<meta name="application-name" content="Апельсин — свежий сайт">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#fc9700">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#fc9700">
```

*Sorry for offtopic. Corrected the question to avoid it.*

Comment: *have a problem with favicon*: What is the problem? Please also supply the relevant code inside the question.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of RealFaviconGenerator. I've just check your site and unfortunately, the checker fails at parsing your homepage page. Maybe this is because it contains non-ASCII characters (just an hypothesis; I'm debugging). But your code looks just fine, icon files are accessible, etc. So you can safely ignore the checker conclusions and consider your icons as correct.

Comment: Oh, and your browserconfig.xml is not declared (although is is present in /fi). Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? the favicon is present [favicon screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPcgj.png)

If you don't see the favicon, sometimes only you need to close your browser and open it again or clear your cache.

Comment: Thanks, but I worry about favicons on mobile devices.